# Passing <object> as a type to the Search method while searching

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to implement SearchAll() which fetches & merges results from different indexes already written through the API. In my case 'Document' for example is a parent type, while, 'Product', 'User' & 'Company' are specific types inherited from the 'Document' class.

I do not wish to pass parent 'Document' to the Search() method, as that would not fetch me the specific types. So, I'm passing 'object' instead. But I am not able to figure how to pass the field name from 'object'.

The code I have written gives me error :

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' to type 'Common.SearchClient.Documents.Document'.

```
private static object SearchAll(string query, int skip = 0, int take = 10)
{
var outDocument = default(Common.SearchClient.Documents.Document);
var docs = _client.Search<object>(s => s
        .Index(Indices.Index(
            GetIndex<Common.SearchClient.Documents.User>().Name,
            GetIndex<Common.SearchClient.Documents.Company>().Name,
            GetIndex<Common.SearchClient.Documents.Product>().Name))
        .From(skip)
        .Size(take)
        .Query(q => q
        .MatchPhrasePrefix(c => c
        .Field(p => p.TryCast(outDocument) ? outDocument.Name : "Name")
        .Analyzer("standard")
        .Boost(1.1)
        .Query(query)
        .MaxExpansions(2)
        .Slop(2)
        .Name("search_all")
        )
    )).Documents;
return docs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I am not able to figure how to pass the field name from 'object'.

You can take advantage of [Nest.Infer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html#nest-infer) methods, so you will be able to access type fields in a strongly typed fashion

```
public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

Field<Document>(p => p.Text)
```

and example usage in `MatchPhrasePrefixz` query

```
await client.SearchAsync<object>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .MatchPhrasePrefix(m => m.Field(Field<Document>(p => p.Text)))));
```

Remember to include this static import in your cs file

```
using static Nest.Infer;
```

Hope that helps.